# Change default of QGIS field calculator: turn off "Only update selected features" (always update all features)

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, default

Is there a setting to change the default so that the checkbox `Only update %1 selected features` in QGIS field calclulator is not checked? As a default behavior, I would like the expression to be applied to all features, even when some features are selected.

If you open the field calculator, a QGIS expression builder dialog opens. There is a checkbox `Only update %1 selected features` that is activated by default: so every time one or more features are selected, only these get updated.

To me, this is very annoying as it happens quite often that I apply an expression and I have features selected that I am not aware of and I have to repeat the whole operation. In fact, my default use of field calculator is to update all features and only in specific cases I want to activate the checkbox `Only update selected features`.

[image]

Comment: IMHO the default behavior should not be changed. The "natural" expection is that when features are selected, all actions - udate, delete, etc - apply only to selected features.